# Linux Deepin doesn't show other networks while scanning when connected

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm using the new distribution [Linux Deepin](http://www.linuxdeepin.com/) based on Ubuntu after having used Ubuntu for the last two years.

After I'm connected to my wireless network, I can't find any other networks scanning for new ones. In other Linux distributions or Windows though, networks will be found.

It seems like a problem with `network-manager`. I installed "Wifi Radar" but that didn't help.

Edited:: laptop information

```
> *-network               
>        description: Ethernet interface
>        product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
>        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>        logical name: eth0
>        version: 01
>        serial: 00:19:db:3d:d1:18
>        size: 10Mbit/s
>        capacity: 1Gbit/s
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd
> autonegotiation
>        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no
> multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
>        resources: irq:43 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fe2ff000-fe2fffff memory:fe2c0000-fe2dffff   *-network
>        description: Wireless interface
>        physical id: 1
>        bus info: usb@1:6
>        logical name: wlan0
>        serial: 00:19:db:9d:d7:c3
>        capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=3.2.0-26-generic firmware=1.7 ip=192.168.1.103 link=yes
> multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Comment: I guess it would help to include details about your hardware in the question.

Comment: is it good to run "lshw" command ? it's edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved simply !...it's tiny problem with this distro 
Open Terminal then type:`sudo iwlist scan` to scan networks and it's done :)
Thanks